# How to speedup for and if loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, sapply

In my current project, I have around 8.2 million rows. I want to scan for all rows and apply a certain function if the value of a specific column is not zero.

```
counter=1
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
if(data[i,8]!=0){
totalclicks=sum(data$Clicks[counter:(i-1)])
test$Clicks[i]=totalclicks
counter=i
  }
}
```

In the above code, I am searching for the specific column over 8.2 million rows and if values are not zero then I will calculate `sum` over values. The problem is that `for` and `if` loops are too slow. It takes 1 hour for 50K rows. I heard that `apply` family is alternative for this. The following code also takes too long:

```
sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) 
if(data[x,8]!=0){
totalclicks=sum(data$Clicks[counter:(x-1)])
test$Clicks[x]=totalclicks
counter=x
})
```

[Updated]
Kindly consider the following as sample dataset:

```
clicks revenue new_column (sum of previous clicks)
  1      0       
  2      0
  3      5        3
  1      0
  4      0
  2      7        8
```

I want above kind of solution, in which I will go through all the rows. If any non-zero revenue value is encountered then it will add all previous values of clicks.

Am I missing something? Please correct me.

Comment: This could probably be done within seconds if you use appropriate vectorization instead of a loop to run through each row. If you provide a reproducible example and expected output, you'll get better help.

Comment: @docendodiscimus: I have updated question by adding the sample dataset.

Comment: how is the 10 calculated?

Comment: I don't understand why the value of `new_column` for the last row is 10 when the only non-zero rows add up to 5?

Comment: Basically (new_column) is calculated as the sum of clicks till previous non zero value in revenue is encountered (including previous non zero value). So the calculation of eight (in the new_column) involves the use of 4+1+3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aggregate()` function can be used for splitting your long dataframe into chunks and performing operations on each chunk, so you could apply it in your example as:

```
data <- data.frame(Clicks=c(1,2,3,1,4,2),
                   Revenue=c(0,0,5,0,0,7),
                   new_column=NA)

sub_totals <- aggregate(data$Clicks, list(cumsum(data$Revenue)), sum)
data$new_column[data$Revenue != 0] <- head(sub_totals$x, -1)
```

Comment: Let me go through it and inform you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer :)